# JBoss - Loading a new module at runtime

Tags: java, jboss, module, runtime, ear

Is it possible to load an added module at run-time?

I have added an optional module to my EAR, I started JBoss and I added the optional module at run-time using CLI. To load that module though I had to restart JBoss which is not what I am looking for.

Is there a way to load it without restart using JBoss CLI?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can try [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/), which does the hot deploy stuff very They
   have a trial version.
2. If you using  JBoos AS 7.0.1 (community project).

   You can go to JBoss administrative panel, There in profile settings
   open Core - Deployment Scanners. Turn on Auto deploy-Exploded (set
   to true), and set the scanner time as per your requirement ( default
   5000 ms) . That it.

Comment: Thank you very much BTW.I did what you suggested and it was loaded but my application fails to see it. You see what I need is to add jars on run-time and my enterprise application being able to load classes from those jars. For the time being I do not want to do anything manually. I want to see first if JBoss can do it for me.

Comment: "You see what I need is to add jars on run-time and my enterprise application being able to load classes from those jars" . I am not able to understand this line can you describe more so i can help what u want point to point.

Comment: I need for example to be able to add new JDBC drivers and be able to load the driver class from my EAR. Adding new modules seem to require a JBoss restart.I just need to know if it is possible without a restart.